# Shell Script to create a tar file whenever a particular folder gets modified

Tags: shell, scripting

New to shell scripting, just wanted to understand how to write a shell script to create a tar file whenever a particular directory gets modified.

When we say modification, its like new files got added/removed to/from that particular directory.

Tarfile should be something like nameofDir_timestamp.tar

find path/to/dir -mtime 10m exec tar -cvf {} ;

Comment: tar -zcf "tarfilename_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S%z(%Z)').tar" path/to/tar

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have bash installed, you could do this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dirname='folder'
dirlastmod='folder-last-modified'

[[ ${dirlastmod} -nt ${dirname} ]] && exit

timestamp=$(date '+%s')

tar -cvf "${dirname}_${timestamp}.tar" "${dirname}"
touch "${dirlastmod}"
```

and add it to a cronjob.

This will check if the directory `folder` is newer than the file `folder-last-modified`, and exit if it's not. If it is, it will create a tar file of the directory `folder`, and use `touch` to update/create the timestamp on the `folder-last-modified` file.